# Flot bar chart highlight color per series

Tags: flot

I have a bar chart with a few series. How can I control what color the highlight color will be on a per series basis? (each of my series is a different colour so I need to highlight them each differently).

I've seen how to do this for a single color throughout the entire chart but I'm needing it specific for each series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `highlightColor` [option](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-data-series) for each series in your data array:

```
var data = [{
    data: [
        [1, 5],
        [2, 3]
    ],
    highlightColor: "#00FF00"
}, {
    data: [
        [1, 2],
        [2, 8]
    ],
    highlightColor: "#FF0000",
}];
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ygrrgkxz/)